# Conveying "Only those who dare to fail greatly can ever achieve greatly."

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

- Only those who dare to fail greatly can ever achieve greatly. (R. F. Kennedy)

What is a natural way to convey the meaning (what makes greatness so great is the risk, hardship, and even possible failure, that it takes to achieve that greatness). Does

- Seuls ceux qui osent échouer grandement peuvent réaliser de grands résultats.

sound idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this not conveying exactly the same meaning, but we have an expression in French:

> Qui ne tente rien n'a rien

We lose the greatness meaning, but convey the idea that if you don't try (and so fear losing) you won't achieve anything.

Comment: J'entends et utilise plutôt «Qui ne risque rien n'a rien». La variante avec tenter est-elle courante ailleurs?

Comment: @Pasunclue Je n'ai jamais entendu celle avec "risquer" (région parisienne), uniquement "tenter". Où est-elle utilisée ?

Comment: @Sacha Je viens du Québec. Je trouve la version avec risquer dans Le Petit Robert, ainsi que dans deux volumes publié par Robert (Proverbes et dictons, Expressions et locutions), mais rien avec tenter (je trouve par contre et tenter et risquer le tout pour le tout dans le dictionnaire). Le Larousse n'a ni l'un ni l'autre (mais est-ce si surprenant?). Le TLFi cite à la fois «Qui ne risque rien...» et «Qui ne tente rien...»

Comment: Voilà l'audimat du «moi aussi» qui recommence! Quelle plaie de vouloir discuter de particularités régionales ici! On cite des dicos, mais ça ne vaut jamais autant que du «chez moi dans ma maison, ma famille, mon environnement social, on utilise ça et les dicos sont deux pas en retard sur la réalité».

Comment: Voici comment la France des 12 dernières années et demi a cru bon substituer une tentative (un risque si marginal qu'on ne le mentionne plus) au risque plus communément évoqué auparavant: [nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=qui+ne+risque+rien%2Cqui+ne+tente+rien&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20risque%20rien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20tente%20rien%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20risque%20rien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20tente%20rien%3B%2Cc0). Pauvre petit Québécois de moi!

Comment: Always a pleasure to see reactions to my rants going the way to prove my rant was justified. Keep going. One day, you'll be all people from France here. And your language will only live in France too. Such a joyous bunch!

Comment: @Pasunclue Merci d'avoir mis le doigt sur cette substitution. Je soupçonne qu'elle est due à à une évolution du sens de l'expression *il ne risque rien* qui veut de moins en moins dire ici, *il ne prends pas de risque* et de plus en plus *il est tranquille, il n'est pas susceptible d'être affecté par quelque chose d'extérieur*. Ceci expliquerait l'essor de *tenter* qui remet l'emphase sur le caractère proactif du sujet.

Comment: @jlliagre Me faudra-t-il croire que nous sommes les deux seuls specimens ici qui existaient il y a douze ans et demi, lorsque l'antique alternative vivotait encore chétivement ses derniers jours?

Answer (score 4):

*Oser échouer grandement* is not idiomatic. A known translation of this Robert F. Kennedy quote is:

> *Seuls ceux qui prennent le risque d’échouer spectaculairement réussiront brillamment.*

I would still stick to Calins' suggestion though or that other one:

> *La fortune sourit aux audacieux.*