# « Qui ne risque/tente rien n'a rien » : origine, évolution ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, proverbes, fréquence-utilisation, évolution-récente

[Quelqu'un](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/conveying-only-those-who-dare-to-fail-greatly-can-ever-achieve-greatly#comment92431_45415) a remarqué une substitution du verbe dans la [présentation](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45415) de l'expression « qui ne [risque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_ne_risque_rien_n%E2%80%99a_rien)/[tente](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_ne_tente_rien_n%E2%80%99a_rien) rien n'a rien » signifiant essentiellement « celui qui n’essaye rien n’arrivera à rien » (Wiktionnaire) et une plus grande fréquence d'emploi [récemment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/conveying-only-those-who-dare-to-fail-greatly-can-ever-achieve-greatly#comment92433_45415) de la version avec *tenter* dans le corpus [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=qui%20ne%20risque%20rien%2Cqui%20ne%20tente%20rien&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20risque%20rien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20tente%20rien%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20risque%20rien%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cqui%20ne%20tente%20rien%3B%2Cc0).

La locution avec *risquer* est attestée en 1798 (DHLF/Rey) et même remarquée ailleurs de manière plus contemporaine [dans](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Leclerc_de_Hauteclocque) l'[histoire](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Wo7UAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:qHVtnSQCR7kC&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22qui%20ne%20risque%20rien%20n%27a%20rien%22&f=false). Mais il semble qu'un [certain nombre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/conveying-only-those-who-dare-to-fail-greatly-can-ever-achieve-greatly#comment92430_45415) de locuteurs trouvent l'emploi avec *risquer* inusité alors que pour d'[autres](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45413/conveying-only-those-who-dare-to-fail-greatly-can-ever-achieve-greatly#comment92429_45415) c'est l'inverse. On note de plus que l'on a *tenter la fortune* (1559) et *tenter fortune* (1740), et *tenter la/sa chance* (DHLF/Rey) ; on trouve ces locutions avec la version du proverbe avec [*tenter*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tenter/0) dans la présentation du TLFi (autrement voir avec *risquer* au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/risquer), [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/risquer/68806) en ligne français-anglais et au LBU14 § 761, en plus des autres sources). Plus généralement, quand on regarde les verbes *risquer* et *tenter* au [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=risquer%2Ctenter&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crisquer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctenter%3B%2Cc0) on voit à première vue un écart croissant en faveur du second...

1. Depuis quand la version du proverbe avec *tenter* est-elle attestée ?
2. La version du proverbe avec *risquer* est-elle en train de sortir d'usage : la plus grande fréquence de l'emploi du proverbe avec *tenter* qui apparaît au corpus *ngram* il y a une décennie reflète-t-elle vraiment une évolution dans l'usage ainsi que dans la langue parlée généralement ; est-ce uniquement en France ou dans toute la francophonie que ça se produirait ?
3. Comment s'expliquerait ce phénomène, se démarque-t-on d'un sens ou assimile-t-on à un autre, la version avec *tenter* est-elle plus recherchée, est-ce relié à une plus grande fréquence à première vue de l'emploi du verbe *tenter* par rapport à *risquer* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On le trouve dès 1836 :

> D'ailleurs, **qui ne tente rien, n'a rien.** C'est clair. Attendre, c'est folie, c'est faire sentinelle près d'une porte qu'un autre plus malin que vous, aura
> soin de vous enlever.
> *Maria Joubert, ou Les chagrins d'une jeune mariée. Tome 1* , Félix Servan

soit une centaine d'années après :

> D'ailleurs, il est certain que dans presque toutes les situations de guerre, **qui ne risque rien n'a rien** : c'est ce que le feu Roy disoit, quand on lui rendoit compte de quelque action où il avoit paru de la témerité...
> Pierre Claude de Guignard, *L'école de Mars*, 1725

et cet extrait de 1761 :

> De même l'Amour peut bien
> Rendre un Amant téméraire.
> Allons, vogue la galère:
> **Qui ne risque rien, n'a rien.**
> *Mazet*, M. Ansaume.

2. le Ngram laisse supposer que la version avec risquer a prédominé jusqu'à la fin du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle où la version avec tenter a décollé, puis dépassé l'autre il y une dizaine d'années.

   [image]

   Je ne peux pas parler pour le reste de la francophonie, mais je peux témoigner que seule la version avec *tenter* me parait familière. Mon entourage semble aussi ne pas connaître la version avec risquer. Je reconnais être surpris car le changement est quand même récent.

Une recherche comparative de "[qui ne tente rien n'a rien](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qui%20ne%20tente%20rien%20n%27a%20rien%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws)" et "[qui ne risque rien n'a rien](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22qui%20ne%20risque%20rien%20n%27a%20rien%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws)" dans les articles de presse laisse quand même supposer une différence notable de popularité entre les deux côtés de l'Atlantique :

Les 50 premières pages de la version avec ***qui ne tente*** proviennent toutes de France, de pays voisins ou africains alors qu'entre un tiers et la moitié des pages contenant la version avec ***qui ne risque*** proviennent du Canada.

3. Je soupçonne que ce phénomène est du à une spécialisation du sens de l'expression *il ne risque rien* qui décrit plutôt quelqu'un face à un risque extérieur absent et pas quelqu'un d'actif pour lequel on préfère dire *il ne prend pas de risque*. Le verbe *tenter* lui garde la notion de risque et ajoute une composante d'initiative personnelle qui manque à risquer.

[**Risquer**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/risquer): **A. 1.**  Exposer (un bien) à un risque.
[**Tenter**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tenter): **III., A.** Entreprendre, avec l'espoir de la réussir, une action qui présente un caractère difficile ou périlleux.

On aurait alors tendance à avoir plus de respect pour quelqu'un qui tente quelque chose et qui fait donc preuve d'audace, plutôt que pour quelqu'un qui risque quelque chose et qui est peut-être plus irréfléchi. La tentative est optimiste, elle a le succès, parfois l'exploit pour objectif, le risque est pessimiste, il se focalise sur la menace, la possibilité d'une perte. On tente de gagner alors qu'on risque de perdre.

Il y a peut-être une différence culturelle. On valoriserait plus d'un côté et moins de l'autre la prise de risque.

Comment: Je trouve le point 3 intéressant. Je comprends l'analyse détaillée ici et sa validité, mais mon analyse personnelle serait différente. Avec risquer, le potentiel d'une perte matérielle me semble explicitement indiquée. Avec tenter, les conséquences néfastes peuvent être très limitées. Ainsi, il serait étrange pour moi d'utiliser «qui ne risque rien n'a rien» s'il s'agit de confirmer que la pharmacie est encore ouverte: prends tes jambes et vas voir. «Qui ne tente rien n'a rien» pourrait par contre convenir, aucun autre désagrément qu'une possible perte de temps n'étant en jeu.

Comment: Ce qui précède n'ayant aucune volonté de prétendre que l'une ou l'autre analyse soit vraie ou fausse. Il est possible que l'une des deux soit plus vraie que l'autre, voire que les réalités locales varient, mais je n'ai pas pas d'opinion solide quant à la valeur de mon interprétation personnelle sur le sujet.

Comment: @Pasunclue Oui, il n'y a pas de vrai et de faux à identifier. Il s'agit plus de chercher à comprendre ce qui explique cette divergence. Pour la pharmacie, je ne vois pas comment je pourrais utiliser le verbe risquer, ou alors, *je vais à la pharmacie mais je prend le risque de trouver porte close*.  C'est un peu long. Avec tenter, il me semble qu'il faudrait un objectif supplémentaire comme : *Je vais tenter d'arriver à la pharmacie avant qu'elle (ne) ferme*. Le TLFI parle d'action présentant un caractère difficile ou périlleux. La perte de temps n'entre pas vraiment dans cette définition.

Comment: @jlliagre Aux côtés de *tenter* une action présentant un caractère difficile ou périeux, il y a aussi *tenter* plus ou moins synonyme d'*essayer*. Peut-être cette acception est-elle plus vivante au Québec qu'ailleurs en francophonie? Dans le même champ sémantique, je pense aussi à *tentative*, terme assez couramment utilisé pour désigner des choses aussi peu risquées qu'un premier jet à la composition, les premiers calculs de la résolution d'un problème ou la construction ratée d'un prototype pour un petit objet usuel ou décoratif, amélioré plus tard («Là, ce sont mes premières tentatives»).

Comment: @Pasunclue *Tentatives* ou *tenter* me semblent souvent impliquer qu'il s'agit de choses difficiles, au moins pour celui qui tente (à part avec "tenter sa chance"), même s'il n'y a pas forcément de risque associé autre que celui d'échouer bien sûr. *Tentative* est bien synonyme d'*essai* par exemple en saut à la perche (2e essai = 2e tentative) mais tentative est plus fort. Essayer est quasiment exclu dans certains cas: *Il tente la face Nord du K2* mais pas *Il essaye la face Nord du K2*.

Comment: Parfaitement d'accord: *tenter* peut impliquer un risque sérieux. Il semble simplement que cette acception soit plus présente à l'esprit de certains aussitôt le terme énoncé, mais qu'elle soit pour d'autres seulement perçue lors de certains contextes particuliers. Je fais partie de ceux qui lui attribuent une valeur plus faible par défaut, et il semble bien que ma perception de la chose n'est pas universelle. Vision personnelle? Usage culturel? À la lumière des infos que tu présentes, je croirais que de mineures variations culturelles existent, qui composent au moins une partie de la réponse.